# Can ‘be it’ be followed by plural?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Be it a book or a movie, a good story is always appreciated.

Can ‘be it’ be followed by plural?

Ex.  Be it books or movies, a good story is always appreciated.

What I thought is that ‘it’ always refers to a singular form of noun. So, ‘be it’ always goes with singular noun. But I am not sure whether it is true or not.

help me with your suggestion.

Comment: *Books* and *movies* are not plural here. They are singular.

Comment: Confusion is still not cleared. Can you add more details? how can books or movies be singular? is there any grammar rule? Because i learned that more than  one in number is called plural.

Comment: Btw, see also [ell.se]

Comment: *Books* here means literature, the printed reading material, not separate books. *Movies* here refers to the medium of films in general, not individual movies. HTH.

Comment: Everyone seems to be missing the obvious point here. The pronoun refers to "a good story" not to books or movies. Your example, incidentally, is not grammatical. You need to say "Be it from a book or a movie, a good story is always appreciated".

Comment: @WS2 No need to get overly confused. The sentence is fine and the question is fine, too. Please see my comment above.

Comment: Kris is not correct here. _Books_ and _movies_ are both plural nouns, regardless of whether they refer to individual books and movies or their respective genres as a whole. It would still be ungrammatical to say, “Books is an important part of cultural heritage”, for instance. And @WS2 is correct that _it_ refers to the story, which means what you’re really saying is, “A good story is always appreciated, whether that good story is books or movies”. That is not necessarily inherently ungrammatical, but it doesn’t make sense semantically.

Comment: *Be* ***it*** *(from) books or movies,* ***a*** *good* ***story is*** *always appreciated.* The singular pronoun **it** references the singular noun **story** and is appropriate. The plural nouns **books or movies** are irrelevant to the sentence construction. (But, as previously noted, **from** needs to be added to make the sentence grammatical.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the British National Corpus (http://bncweb.lancs.ac.uk), all the examples shown (with the construction "be it + noun 1 or noun 2") suggested the use of the singular form of the nouns that come after it.

Here are a few examples I retrieved from the corpus:-

- When he commits himself to an assignment — be it a poem, a book, a song, or merely aiding a fellow-scribbler's itch, he does it with gusto — con brio , as he might annotate one of his scores.
- Not exactly, because this very mimicry of the dominant, be it a literary trope or cultural actuality, involved a scandalous inversion.

Answer (score -2):

"It" plural pronouns "they", "them", and "those"
So, Be they a book or a movie, a good story is always appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

*Be it* is singular, *books* and *movies* are plural. When used with plurals, the *be it* transforms to *be they*, and the rest of your sentence also transforms to the plural.

So, *Be it books or movies, a good story is always appreciated* is re-cast as *Be they books or movies, good stories are always appreciated*. But, a good writer would re-cast that again to, *Be they from books or movies, good stories are always appreciated* (added the word "from").